# How do I use iptables to do port forwarding from one to another port on the same host?

Tags: iptables

How do I use iptables to forward all requests to a port (say 1443) to another port on the same host (say 443)?

This should also be done for requests from another computer.

Comment: why do you need this if I may ask?

Comment: @HrvojeŠpoljar Some applications that can't guarantee they will be started by UID 0 start on a high-number port by default, and it is up to you to reconfigure or NAT/Proxy if you want to use on a lower port. For example, Tomcat Java application container runs on ports 8080 and 8443 by default. If I recall correctly, BT Diamond's IPControl DNS engine runs on a high-numbered port and expects either IPTABLES-based NAT or a forwarding/caching BIND on port 53 to get to it.

Comment: I see, this approach also requires root access. But certainly if some application is not safe; it's better to run it as normal user than as root. Normally applications run as root and then privileges are dropped to user privileges when it 'daemonizes'.

Answer (score 2):

You need rule which will update 'nat' tables PREROUTING chain like this :

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 443